# Passing multiple values with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a couple of inputs that have a different `data-id`.  The data-id's are 'single' and 'multi'.

I somehow need to get the `data-id` for `item_single` and `item_multipule` in such a way that I can pass them into my db field called `shop_shipping_rule_type`

How would I do this?

Below is an example of how it gets handled to be past into the controller.

**Code:**

```
var shop_shipping_rule_id = $('#shop_shipping_rule_id').val();
var shop_shipping_rule_name = $('#shop_shipping_rule_name').val();


$.post("<?php echo site_url("admin/websites/{website_id}/settings/shop/ajax_shipping_rule_op"); ?>", {
is_ajax: 1,
shop_shipping_rule_country_or_region_code: shop_shipping_rule_country_or_region_code,
shop_shipping_rule_item_single: shop_shipping_rule_item_single,
shop_shipping_rule_item_multiple: shop_shipping_rule_item_multiple,
shop_shipping_rule_id: shop_shipping_rule_id,
shop_shipping_rule_name: shop_shipping_rule_name,
```

Comment: Best to show us the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
var item_single_id = $('#item_single').data('id')
```

or

use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
var item_single_id = $('#item_single').attr('data-id')
```